# How can I remove styrofoam bits from my equipment?

Tags: cleaning, removal

Is there a way to remove [Styrofoam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styrofoam) bits from my equipment efficiently?

[image]

Comment: What type of equipment?

Comment: Acetone solvent will dissolve it down into a small pile of white goo at about 1/100th the volume, but then of course that is assuming that the acetone will not harm your equipment and if you don't mind the smell ;-)

Comment: @maple_shaft Then the question becomes, "How do I remove melted Styrofoam goo from my equipment?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an [air compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_compressor), you can get an attachment called an [air blow gun](http://www.sears.com/craftsman-1-4-in-blow-gun-professional/p-00916387000P).

[image]

Since Styrofoam is so light, you should be able to simply blow it away. This tool is also helpful, if you want to make your friends laugh.

[image]

If you don't have a compressor, you could use [canned air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_duster) to blow the Styrofoam away.

[image]

If you don't have that either, you could always use your lungs.

- Inhale deeply.
- Press your lips together to form a circular opening.
- Exhale hard.
- Repeat until the Styrofoam is gone, or you've passed out.

---

Thanks BMitch for pointing out the more obvious solution... Use a f***ing ShopVac!

[image]

<sub>*You can set the vac to blow, if you still want to blow the Styrofoam around for a bit.*</sub>

Comment: Looks like me when I wake up in the morning...

Comment: I prefer a shopvac, blowing the styrofoam around is just going to get it stuck somewhere else.

Comment: @BMitch So, you use the air gun to blow them off that too. What, you have better things to do with your weekend?

Comment: @BMitch Some shopvacs don't have a *blow* setting.

Comment: @Tester101 I prefer shopvacs that suck.

Comment: are there sucker version cause blowing often blow them all over the place and I don't want them to be inside my nose or any part of my body.